# How to control UV mapping distortion

Tags: geometry, perspective, affinetransform, distortion, uv-mapping

The illustration below shows how I expect the UV mapping to be applying the texture and how it is really being applied. This was a big surprise to me, my conclusion was if I could draw faces with four vertices this wouldn't be an issue, but I am using WebGL where I have to stick with triangles...

- Is there a name for this phenomenon?
  (EDIT: I found out that this phenomenon is called affine texture mapping, as
  opposed to perspective texture mapping
  https://mtrebi.github.io/2017/03/15/texture-mapping-affine-perspective.html)
- What could be a possible solution to achieve the expected result with WebGL?

[image: UV mapping: Expectation vs reality?]

### **EDIT:**

I fixed my visualisation of the "expected distortion" and added another visualization below for a use case to make it more clear. What trips me up is the diagonal triangle edges being curved. Sure that this cannot be represented with polygon triangles. So how could I achieve this mapping?

[image: desired UV mapping visualized in illustrator]

### **EDIT 2:**

I had a hard time with this, got it so far that I was able to distort the projection that it (kind of?) fits the pseudo perspective distortion of each face. It's close, but not right yet. The distortion is almost right. I think I am missing a little math lesson here to interpolate the right way. I'm fine with the overall look, I just need the texture to be seamless.

[image: Almost right...]

My fragment shader looks like this:

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;
in vec2 vUv;
in float vRailsRatio;
in float vLastUPosition;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {

  float uDifference = vUv.x - vLastUPosition;
  float step = vUv.y;
  if (vRailsRatio < 1.) {
    step = 1. - vUv.y;
  }
  float newU = vLastUPosition + uDifference * mix( 1. , 1./vRailsRatio  , step) ;

  fragColor = texture(uSampler, vec2(newU, vUv.y));

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Rabbid76. Though not the answer I was hoping for, as the geometry should be able to "bend" in any direction in 3d space. I give it a try with the shader. The tesselation is a workaround but it looks not so smooth.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if I understand you right, but my main question is how I can get rid of the weird zig zag mapping as shown in the first picture at the bottom. Dividing into more narrower triangles only adds more tiny zig zags.

Comment: So I think my question is about perspective interpolation then.

Comment: The second image is just the bigger picture. If you take two triangles from the curved shape you end up with the situation in the first image.

Comment: Anyway the solution is simple. The v-coordinate of a fragment is the angle of vector from the center to the this fragments divided by 180°.

Comment: I tried your solution @Rabbid76. It didn't work for me in this situation.

Comment: Ok, thanks... Could you then provide a little more information about your solution?

Comment: It looks like this when I tried with your suggested solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo4Qy.png